# Server echoes warnings/errors that make a json expected response to be invalid

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, phpmailer

I'm currently writing an ajax form with jquery.
The form is handled with a PHP script then the information is sent via the PHPMailer lite class. (http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php)

This is the PHP code:

```
    if ($mail->Send())
        echo '{"message":"Mensaje enviado con éxito","status":"ok"}';
    else
        echo '{"message":"Ocurió un error al envíar el mensaje, intentelo más tarde.","status":"fail"}';
```

I discovered this problem when the email submitted by the user is not a valid one, resulting in the following error:

`Invalid address: E-mail:Invalid address: E-mail:Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail`

I should test the email. Ok. But the problem is that the previous error message "gets in the way" and corrupts the response. So I can solve the email error, but any other warning/error would corrupt the response.

A 'corrupted' response example:

> Invalid address: E-mail:Invalid address: E-mail:Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail 
>   {"message":"Ocurió un error al envíar el mensaje, intentelo más tarde.","status":"fail"}

(First line should not be there)

And this is the javascript (jquery) part:

```
        $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "contact.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data.status == 'fail')
            {
                do something with data.message;
            }
            else if(data.status == 'ok')
            {
                do something else with data.message;
            }
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

Any help with this? :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

Its a long shot but have you tried

```
@ if ($mail->Send())
```

The @ suppresses php errors on a given line of code.

Comment: Well, only use this as a very last resort... hiding problems does not mean they are solved.

Comment: Well now its a start, if he wants to do it properly he'd have to look into the Send() function. This is most likely running on a test server with no smtp settings configured and will work live. Not everything is an enteprise level application....

Comment: Well, yes, not everything is an enterprise level application :). Then who cares about coding standards and logic anymore :).

Comment: you are right, this problem happens on the local server which I was too lazy to configure to be able to send mail (wamp). I'm not focusing on the "sendmail problem" but more on the server echoing messages that can 'corrupt' an expected response. (Because jquery callback function won't fire when the response is not a valid json string)

Comment: Did this work by any chance? If not you can send us the code for mail->Send() and we can help you more?